# How to align the edge of the circle together?

Tags: for-loop, lua, position, coronasdk, shapes

How to align the edge of the circle together? The edge of the boxes are align but my circles circumference/edge are not align but instead they occupying each other spaces..

```
    local areaPadding = 5
    local topPadding = 160
    local answerOffset = 6
    local area = answer_rect.width - (areaPadding*-5)
    local answerHeight = (area-topPadding-(answerOffset*#q.answers))/#q.answers
    local textX = numberX + 20
    local textW = _W - textX - 24

    local y = answer_rect.x + areaPadding + topPadding
    local howManyAnswers = #q.answers
```

-- make sure answers fit screen size if neccessary decrease answerHeight
        local offset = (_W - (howManyAnswers * (answerHeight+answerOffset) - answerOffset)) * 0.5

```
    for i=1, howManyAnswers do
        local rect = display.newCircle(quizGroup, offset + (answerHeight+answerOffset)*(i-1), y, answerHeight, answerHeight )
        rect.anchorX, rect.anchorY = 0, 0
        rect.id = "answer"
        rect.index = i
        rect:setFillColor(0.1)
        rect:addEventListener("touch", buttonTouched)

        local answer = display.newText({parent=quizGroup, text=q.answers[i], width=textW, height=0, font=native.systemFont, fontSize=150})
        answer.x = rect.x + rect.width * 0.3
        answer.y = rect.y + rect.height * 0.5
        answer.anchorX = 0
        answer:setFillColor(1)
    end
end
```

end

[image]
[image]

Comment: y is the vertical axis, x the horizontal axis. simply use x and width values instead of y and height values. it's simple maths... come on

Comment: my y is assigned as a local variable and i already change it to x but still it ruin the application i think its on the equation of the variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
local _W = display.contentWidth
local _H = display.contentHeight

local areaPadding = 12
local topPadding = 16
local answerOffset = 30 -- you put in this space labels
local area = answer_rect.height - (areaPadding*2.5)
local howManyAnswers = #q.answers
local textX = numberX + 20
local textW = _W - textX - 24
local answerHeight = (area-topPadding-(answerOffset*#q.answers))/howManyAnswers 
local y = answer_rect.x + areaPadding + topPadding 
-- make sure answers fit screen size if neccessary decrease answerHeight
local offset = (_W - (howManyAnswers * (answerHeight+answerOffset))) * 0.5

for i=1, howManyAnswers do
  local rect = display.newRect(quizGroup, offset + answerOffset +(answerHeight+answerOffset)*(i-1), y, answerHeight, answerHeight)
  rect.anchorX, rect.anchorY = 0, 0
  rect.id = "answer"
  rect.index = i
  rect:setFillColor(0.1)
  rect:addEventListener("touch", buttonTouched)

  local label = display.newText({parent=quizGroup, text=i..".", font=native.systemFont, fontSize=20})
  label.x = rect.x - answerOffset * 0.5
  label.y = rect.y + 0.5 * rect.height 
  label:setFillColor(0.4)

  local answer = display.newText({parent=quizGroup, text=q.answers[i], width=textW, height=0, font=native.systemFont, fontSize=150})
  answer.x = rect.x + rect.width * 0.5
  answer.y = rect.y + rect.height * 0.5
  answer:setFillColor(1)
end
```

Comment: Idurniat many thanks about the rect(shape) but my text answer and text number label is not align to it since i forgot to put the block of codes and the image is above...

Comment: I add neccessary code to align labels and answers properly so everything should work fine:) Some elements may need to be smaller or bigger to look better.

Comment: My goodness you must have been heaven sent idurniat lol.. the 2 boxes has the position right but the last oneis empty i tried to add "answer.anchorX = 0" it shows but it doesnt fit,, ill just increase/decrease your values.Thank you very much..your good at math..

Comment: Idurniat how will I able to adjust the rect shape to fit on the edge of the screen? and also how can i make it circle? newCircle() works but it ruin the application.. See the pic above.

Comment: It depends how you handle scaling in your app. You can find  the scale setting in config.lua Read more about it on Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html). Notice that your rect is actually square with side equal `answerHeight`. How does circles ruin your app?

Comment: Ok ill review it, idurniat how will i able to fit the square on the screen? i keep reviewing and experimenting your code...

Comment: Generally `display.contentWidth` indicate width of screen but it depends  how you handle scaling in your app.  In `letterbox` mode `display.contentWidth` returns the content width, including the letterbox area. A good introduction to scaling you find in [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2010/11/20/content-scaling-made-easy/) and [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/10/28/resolution-independence-adaptive-content-scaling-in-corona/). Good luck:)

Comment: Thanks for the info idurniat i already adjust your code to fit in the edge "local area = answer_rect.height - (areaPadding*2.5)" i edit this thing to this "local area = answer_rect.width - (areaPadding*2.5)" and i just the x and y axis of the number text...